# Angular 6 http.get - displaying returned object in console

Tags: angular, typescript

There's a helpful Angular tutorial here:

https://coursetro.com/posts/code/154/Angular-6-Tutorial---Learn-Angular-6-in-this-Crash-Course

In the data.services.ts file there is a simple http.get which returns a json payload:

```
return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
```

I was hoping to "inspect" the payload in the Chrome developer tool and added this code:

```
console.log("Payload = " + this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'));
```

But what I see in Chrome is this:

```
Payload = [object Object]
```

How can I "see" the raw JSON data returned via a console.log()?

The reason I'd like to inspect the payload is that my requirement is to read an XML response.  I know I have to covert the XML to JSON but I want to be sure I'm getting the XML.

Comment: Are you using ` HttpClient`?

Comment: I believe your Payload is an Array of Array so it wont be showed like you want in the console. You can put a debugger point and manually go, with the mouse, over it and see its properties. Can you do a print-stamp of what you get when you go over with the mouse?

Comment: Shashikant -- Yes, I'm using HttpClient.  Thanks for contributing!

Answer (score 6):

The get method of http return an observable. An observable will work only when it has been subscribed.

```
this.http.get('some url ') // No api call will be made. You haven't subscribe it yet. You can check your browser network tab.
```

so write it like this:

```
console.log('Print:' + this.http.get('')); // will get 'Print: + [object object] because this is not the data that has returned but an observable object.'
```

To actual get the data, subscribe to the observable, like this:
try this:

```
this.http.get('some url ').subscribe(responseData => console.log(responseData));
```

Comment: Shadab -- This is a great clarification -- thank you.  Now I can see my JSON response array clearly.  My next challenge is to deal with an XML response.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm new at Angular 6, but since http.client returns a Observable we have to subscribe to it to get the result, and to output value to console instead of [Object object] you have to pass it to the `console.log()` as parameter:

```
this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').subscribe(
  data => console.log("Payload = ", data);
);
```

Comment: subscribing is correct, but the console.log() would also return Payload = [object Object], ....

Comment: Are you sure? I got this code from the same course the post author got his: this.data.getUsers().subscribe(
      data => this.users$ = data 
    );

Comment: your concatining a string. If you output just via console.log(data) you will get your output.

Comment: console.log("Payload = ", data) comma sign except + will be correct

Comment: Oh, didn't paid attention to that! Thanks!

Comment: Marcello -- thanks for contributing here!  I too am very new to Angular and it's been a real challenge for me!

Answer (score 0):

aonther way would be to get the full response by setting the response option. This can also be used to read headers from the response.

```
  this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users',{ observe: 'response' })
   .subscribe(
    response => console.log(response.body)
  );
```

[Angular.io Guide - Reading the full response](https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response)

Comment: Yes, Dirk, this also worked.  Thanks for clearing up some misunderstanding I had!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're only logging out the payload and do not concatenate it with a string ("Payload = ...").

Doing this will turn the http.get method output into its toString() interpretation, [object Object]:

```
console.log("Payload = " + this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'));
```

Do this instead:

**Data service**

```
someMethod() {
    return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
}
```

**Use the service**

```
someOtherMethod() {
    this.dataService.someMethod().subscribe(payload => console.log(payload));
}
```

---

You can do the following for a quick test in your service (but keep in mind that no value is returned):

```
someMethod() {
    this.http
        .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
        .subscribe(payload => console.log(payload));
}
```