# How to use HttpClient to both report on progress and return data from a slow method?

Tags: angular

I've got a rather heavy api method that needs a progress spinner.  I'm looking at using a Bootstrap progress bar.  So I'm reading through the HttpClient docs and a few examples that handle the events like this.  That's great, but where is my data landing?  Do I need to chain another subscribe on to the end to map data into my object?

What I need is an example of calling a method that returns a list of my model class, and with progress events.

However, here is an excerpt from the docs 
How would one use httpevents with this method if it was going to be slow.

https://angular.io/guide/http

```
getConfig() {
  return this.http.get<Config>(this.configUrl)
    .pipe(
      retry(3), // retry a failed request up to 3 times
      catchError(this.handleError) // then handle the error
    );
}
```

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/http#listening-to-progress-events

Comment: yes, I seen that but how do I not only get the events but the data being returned as well?

Comment: Well you're now getting an observable of the whole [`HttpResponse`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpResponse), so look at that.

Comment: ok, good point, ill try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a loader service.

So in your request you can do like:

```
getConfig() {

 this.loaderService.display(true);                <-- Show the loading

 return this.http.get<Config>(this.configUrl)
 .pipe(
  retry(3), // retry a failed request up to 3 times
  catchError(
   this.loaderService.display(false);             <-- Hide the loading in case of error      
   this.handleError
  ) // then handle the error
 );

   this.loaderService.display(false);             <-- Hide the loading       

}
```

I used that tutorial -> https://medium.com/@zeljkoradic/loader-bar-on-every-http-request-in-angular-6-60d8572a21a9

Showing how I do to get the data being returned by the api method:

I created a service that is responsible for the communication with the API.

**service** -> let's call configService

```
    //First way
    getConfigInService() {
     const response = 
     this.http.get<Config>(this.configUrl);
     return response;
    }

    //Second way
    getConfigInService() {
     return this.http.get<Config>(this.configUrl)
     .pipe (
      map((config: any) => {
       return config.data; --> Have to analyse your json structure that is returned
      })
     );
    }
```

Then in my component I call that service and treat the returns:

**component**

```
  private getConfigInComponent(): void {
   this.loaderService.display(true);          <-- Show the loading
   this.configService.getConfigInService()
     .subscribe( (config: any) => {
      this.config = config;
      this.loaderService.display(false);      <-- Hide the loading

     }, (error: any) => {
     console.error("Erro-> ", error);
     this.loaderService.display(false);      <-- Hide the loading in case of error
   });
```

Here is a link that may could help -> [Angular 6 http.get - displaying returned object in console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52325417/angular-6-http-get-displaying-returned-object-in-console)

Comment: This might be what works for me.  Don't really need to tap into the exact status of how much longer the method is going to take, just to indicate that its "busy".  Http calls can sometimes take a few seconds.  Thanks  However, im still trying to figure out how to get the events AND the data being returned by the api method.

Comment: I edited my answer with the code that consumes the API method. Hope that helps o/

Comment: did you mean to call show() / hide() instead of display(true) / display(false) on the loaderservice?  The loader isnt showing for me yet.  Im calling show/hide on either side of calling my service method

Comment: I used the mentioned tutorial as a base to create my own loader service. Take a look at this test [repo](https://github.com/sibelly/angular-with-datatablesnet) of mine, I added the loader service. Hope that helps you to understand the structure. Also look at this [link](https://medium.com/@mirokoczka/3-ways-to-communicate-between-angular-components-a1e3f3304ecb), showing how to do communicate between components.

Comment: hooray, I managed to get my loaderbar working thanks to the example in the link you provided.  Just had to restart Visual Studio. This gave me a chance to learn about http interceptors.  Seems real similar to the features in .NET core startup and taping in to the request/response pipeline.  VS 2017 seems to have numerous quirks when dealing with typescript & angular.

Comment: I'm glad that helped you, light in our coding journey ;)